# Android Eclipse - loggin not removed when using proguard

Tags: android, eclipse, logging, proguard

In my Android project in Eclipse, I have the following settings to remove the log messages:

In **project.properties**:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-
optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

and in **proguard-project.txt**:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
 public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
 public static int v(...);
 public static int i(...);
 public static int w(...);
 public static int d(...);
 public static int e(...);
}
```

But, when I run the app, I still see the log messages in the log window.

Are my settings correct?

Did I miss anything else?

Why are the log messages still logged?

Please help.